# Get data payload of android notification on dismiss

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications with data payload to my app.

When i send a notification, if my app is running (foreground) i get the data overriding the `onMessageReceived()` from `FirebaseMessagingService` class.

If my app is not running the notification is sent to the "system tray" and when the user click's in notification my app start and i can get the data with the `getExtras` of the intent.

But, how could i get the data if the user dismiss the notification in "system tray"?

I need to write some background service that "listen" to the notifications to get this?

Comment: I think you will have to manage the notifcation yourself to do this, instead of letting firebase generate the notification

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are sending notifications from the Firebase console. These messages are always `notification messages`. If a `notification message` has an accompanying data payload then that data is only available to your application if the user taps the notification. If the user never taps the notification then that data will not be available to your app. So you should not use `notification messages` to send app critical data to your application.

If you send `data messages` they are always handled by `onMessageReceived` callback. At that point you can either silently handle the message or display your own notification. So use `data messages` if you want to be sure that your application has an opportunity to handle the data in the message.

Comment: I am not using the Firebase Console. I wrote some PHP code to send the notification and the data message together like this:

'to' => "/topic/test",
'notification' => "test",
'data' => "test"

But, i see in the Firebase Documentation that we can send only notification, only the data or both. I will try send just the data to test if it works

Comment: FYI it should be /topics/test, also notification and data payloads have a specific format they can't just be strings.

Comment: Hello @Arthur. I put this as a example of how i am sending the message.

Actualy i create a JSON and then send over POST to Firebase server.

Comment: I tried with only data message and if my app is running foreground or in background (recent apps list) the onMessageReceived is called.

But, if i close (remove) the app from recent list, the message is not delivered/received because the onMesssageReceived not get called.

Comment: This is likely do to a manufacturer restriction on the device, not allowing services to be started for applications that are not running or in the background. Have you tried this on another device or an emulator?

Comment: Yes, tried with 3 diferent devices and emulator. onMessageReceived is never called if the app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to store that data ?

if you want to store that data then write your code in OnReceive() method and write Database insertion code in it.

and put one flag in it like "Dismissed=true"
and if user open your notification then make it false and you can get your result.

There is no specific method to detect whether your app's notification is dismissed or not. So you have to manually maintain that data.

Comment: I am using onMessageReceived() to store the data.

The problem is that onMessageReceived() is only called when my app is running.

If my app is not  running the notification is delivery to "notification tray" and this way, i only get the data by the intent.getExtras() if the user "open" the notification.

If him dismiss the notification the data is lost and i cant get it.